# SSRS 2008 and System.Drawing FileIOPermissions

Tags: .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am developing a report for use on an SSRS 2008 server which has dynamic images.  The file name of the image is one of the fields in the dataset, and I have successfully managed to get the correct image to display by setting the image source to EXTERNAL and using a file URI to the network share that the image is stored on.

For giggles, let's say that URI is file://server1/share/subfolder/image.jpg

Now I am trying to center that image in the image box, which, after a bit of research, should be as easy as subtracting the width of the image from the width of the image box, and setting the image box's left padding to half of the difference.  Pretty standard stuff.

But, the problem I'm having is in trying to use the system.drawing reference to access the image file.

I have the following code, which should work:

```
System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("file://server1/share/subfolder/image.jpg").GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).Width
```

...but it does not.  In Report Builder, I get the oh so helpful "#Error" when I put that code as the expression in a text box (for testing).  So I pulled down the rdl file and loaded it up in BIDS where I can see the real error.  The real error is:

> Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)

... and I get WHY this is happening, because the .net 2.0 system.drawing reference needs the proper permissions set... but I don't know WHERE to set it.  I think it will likely have to be in multiple places: one where Report Builder 3.0 on my local client can see it, one where BIDS can see it, and one where the report server itself can see it.

I appreciate any help you can offer!

Comment: Doesn't the imagebox have a center value for the sizing property?

Comment: No.  It has AutoSize, Fit, FitProportional, and Clip.